# How to fetch data from mongo db by object key php

Tags: php, mongodb

I am new to mongo db. I am trying to fetch record based on age key but the query always returns empty result.

Here is JSON string

```
 "age_premium": {
  "age": {       
    "65": {
      "Plan A": "136.24",
       "Plan B": "140.33",
      "Plan F": "172.72",
      "Plan G": "142.95",
      "Plan N": "117.45" 
  },
   "66": {
     "Plan A": "136.24",
     "Plan B": "140.33",
     "Plan F": "172.72",
     "Plan G": "142.95",
     "Plan N": "117.45" 
  }}}
```

I want to fetch data according to age value.

I tried to fetch using this query

```
$collection->find(array('age_premium.age'=>'65'));
```

Comment: `age_premium.age` is an object, not a string. In v3.6 you will be able to use `$objectToArray` within aggregation framework. Until then, your only option is MapReduce, which is rather an ETL tool, and is not recommended for operational queries. Also, bear in mind that types matter: when you compare strings, '8' > '70' > '120'.

Comment: @AlexBlex so what is the solution for now?

Comment: Change schema so that `age` is an array, and embedded documents has age as a number.

Answer (score 0):

For now you can use [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) javascript evaluator:

```
$collection->find(array('$where'=>'for(var i in this.age_premium.age){if(i == 65){return true}} return false'));
```

Which loops through all properties of `age_premium.age`, do type conversion, and compare the value **for each document**. It is extremely slow and cannot use indexes. It might be okay as a quick patch, but you really need to change structure of the document to support this kind of queries.